# Использование html как шаблона в php

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, есть ли способ для подстановки значений переменных в загружаемый html ?
Допустим, имеет template.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>УХХХХ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../template/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?=$html?>
</body>
<script src="../../template/js/print.js"></script>-->
</html>
```

и необходимо вставить в место $html какой-либо кусок,переданный  как аргумент функции, например :

```
function somefunction($html)
{
echo file_get_contents('template.html');
}
```

Есть возможность как это реализовать встроенными функциями или всё таки надо писать свой парсер или использовать шаблонизатор?

Comment: Функцию измените таким образом: `function somefunction($html) { return file_get_contents($html); }`, и вместо переменной вызывайте функцию, передавая аргументом вызываемый файл: `<?= somefunction('template.html') ?>`

Comment: @Эдуард, я всё таки неверное сформулировал вопрос. Как при загрузке template.html можно вставить значение ранее присвоенное $html, при том чтобы этот кусок (результат выполнения somefunction) можно было использовать дальше? например добавить еще кусок html а только потом вывести на экран? вариант использования include не подходит тк не будет работать $somevar=include('template')

Comment: `php` и есть шаблонизатор. зачем на базе шаблонизатора изобретать .. шаблонизатор?! поменяй расширение html на php и подключи файл. можно сделать как другие либы: `ob_start -> extract -> eval -> ob_end`.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так устроена шаблонизация во всех шаблонизаторах на пыхе. Просто выполните код нативно. Ведь пыха сама по себе и есть шаблонизатор. Родилась такой и такой остаётся по сей день.

```
$tmpl = '
<html><?= $foo ?></html>
';
function render($tmpl, array $params = []): string
{
    ob_start();
    extract($params);
    eval('?>' . $tmpl . '<?php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
echo render($tmpl, ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Результат:

```
<html>bar</html>
```

Если будете хранить шаблоны в `php` файлах, то `eval` можно будет заменить на `require`. Что по сути одно и тоже.

Comment: Обращение к $tmpl лучше заменить на вызов `func_get_arg(0)`, это позволит передавать в шаблон переменные с именем `tmpl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function somefunction($html)
{
    $htmlForAdd = '<p>Example</p>'
    $html = str_replace('<?=$html?>', $htmlForAdd, $html )
    echo file_get_contents('template.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вам подойдет банальный `include` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

```
function somefunction($html)
{
    include('template.html');
}
```